# "Weaker" postulates for a group?

Tags: group-theory

In some learning resources I have, it has been claimed that the group axiom defining the identiy $e$ $$a \cdot e = e \cdot a = a$$ and the group axiom defining the inverse element $$a \cdot b = b \cdot a = e$$ can be replaced by the "weaker" statements $$a \cdot e = a$$ and $$a \cdot b = e$$.

The argument proceeds by asking the reader to consider elements $a$, $b$ and $c$ in group $G$ such that $a \cdot b = e$ and $b \cdot c = e$, then $$b \cdot a = (b \cdot a) \cdot e = (b \cdot a) \cdot (b \cdot c) = b \cdot (a \cdot b) \cdot c = b \cdot e \cdot c = b \cdot c = e$$

I am unhappy with this, because at the very end, the claim that $b \cdot e \cdot c = b \cdot c$ relies on the fact that $e \cdot c = c$, but we are supposed to only be working from $c \cdot e = c$

The other weaker form is then "proved" with $$a = a \cdot e = a \cdot (b \cdot a) = (a \cdot b) \cdot a = e \cdot a$$ which is all very well except for the fact that it now uses $a \cdot b = b \cdot a = e$ which I feel has been proved on shaky ground.

Am I right to be concerned with this argument/approach, or are my logic circuits shortcircuiting somewhere?

Is the assertion that the properties/axioms/postulates for a group can be replaced with such a "weaker" form correct?

Comment: Your unhappiness with the proof of $ba=e$ can be easily resolved: Don't use $ec=c$ (because, as you say, that has not been established yet), but $be=b$, i.e., $bec=(be)c=bc$.

Comment: @mxian Of course. I was staring at too long and there was a shortcircuit! Thank you 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is correct that it suffices to expect the presence of a right identity and a right inverse for every element. It is more direct to immediately deduce that given the other axioms (well, using associativity) every right identity will be a left identity and every right inverse will be a left inverse. All of this holds too if you swap the role of right and left.

This relies on the following: $a^2=a$ implies that $a=e$. This fact is already deducible given only a one-sided identity and one-sided inverse (but it has to be the same side! I advise you to come up with a proof). Indeed, suppose that $ab=e$ then

$$
(ba)^2=(ba)(ba)=b(ab)a=b(e)a=(be)a=ba\implies ba=e
$$

from which we then have

$$
ea=(ab)a=a(ba)=ae=a\,.
$$

---

Regarding your concerns:

> the claim that $b⋅e⋅c=b⋅c$ relies on the fact that $e⋅c=c$, but we are supposed to only be working from $c⋅e=c$

We *are* only using $ce=c$! Indeed, $bec=(be)c=b(ec)$. While we know nothing about $ec$ per se we know something about $be$ and associativtiy allows us to  alternate between these two expressions. This was already pointed out in the comments by *mxian*.

Comment: Thank you for the thorough and insightful response, @mrtaurho  Much appreciated!

Comment: @Ken_M_W Glad to help! :)